# Determining north using the android phone

Tags: android, compass-geolocation, sensors

I looked over SensorManager and was still unsure, how do I detect if the phone is looking at true north (or any other direction for that matter).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are just looking for a sample, the publishers of [Professional Android 2 Application Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470565527) have all their [example code available for download](https://media.wiley.com/product_ancillary/27/04705655/DOWNLOAD/Professional%20Android%202%20Code%20Example%20Projects.zip) and there is a compass application in chapter 14.

Comment: That compass example is exactly what i was looking for!